# ¿Como puedo refrescar un formulario hecho con ajax para que los inputs queden limpios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un formulario hecho con ajax usando `Ajax.BeginForm` este lo tengo dentro de una modal, el problema que poseo es que al enviar el formulario hago que la modal se cierre con `jQuery` pero si vuelvo abrir la modal los valores de los inputs que había ingresado con anterioridad siguen ahí... necesito que al enviar el formulario se refresque esa modal para que se limpien los input de mi formulario.

¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Lo que intente fue que coloca en la funcion `onComplete` un `$("input").val(" ")` pero no se si existe alguna otra mejor forma de hacer, como mencionaba de un principio quizás refrescar la modal al enviar el formulario o bien limpiar los input de otra forma.

Comment: para empesar por que no colocas el codigo a ver que estas haciendo mal

Comment: No tengo ningun error en mi codigo por eso no lo coloque, solo quiero saber si existe alguna otra forma mejor para hacer esto, o bien si se puede refrescar la modal. Con en `$("input").val(" ")` me funciona bien.

Comment: pues si te funciona bien , que es lo que buscas en realidad?

Comment: Lo que coloque en la pregunta... si es que existe otra forma de limpiarlos al hacer submit con un form ajax o bien refrescar la modal al enviar el form. Es lo mismo que mencione en la pregunta.

Comment: puedes intentar con `onSubmit="this.reset()"`

Comment: `onSubmit` seria una función que debo hacer o seria el evento de `jQuery` o una funcion del `Ajax.BeginForm`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79238/discussion-between-vcasas-and-andy-gibbs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba con esta function después del `submit`

```
    function limpiar()
    {
    settimeout('document.form.reset()',2000);//le dices al form que se resetee
    }

    onsubmit="return limpiar()"

//una solucion rapida enla etiqueta form
<form action="" onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">

//otro metodo 

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function reset() {
        document.formulario.campo.value = "";
        return true; 
    }
</script>


<form name='formulario' action='' method='post'onsubmit='return reset()'
>

    <input name="campo" type="text">
```

Comment: exactamente editare la respuesta para que veas otro ejemplo hay mil formas de limpiar el formulario solo hay que investigar!!

Comment: Seria genial si me colocas otros ejemplos, De igual forma probare con esa.

Comment: edite la respuesta y te puse otro ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

aqui hay un ejemplo muy claro de como usted puede realizar la operacion

```
<form id="formEjemplo">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre...">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Edad...">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email...">
     <select>
        <option value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
        <option value="0">Mexico</option>
        <option value="0">Estados Unidos</option>
     </select>
     <label>Sexo:</label>
     <input type="radio" name="sexo">M
     <input type="radio" name="sexo">F
     <button type="button" id="btnLimpiar">Limpiar</button>
</form>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $("#btnLimpiar").click(function(event) {
       $("#formEjemplo")[0].reset();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: No es lo que busco, gracias igual.